# Tables with optional rows

Tags: tables

I defined some macros to store data. Them, I typeset them in a table.
If one of the macro is not executed (the corresponding data is not available, 
the row should not appear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\version}[1]{%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\theversion}{#1}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\revised}[1]{%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\therevised}{#1}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\approved}[1]{%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\theapproved}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\mytable}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.6\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\theversion}}{}{Version: &\theversion\\}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\therevised}}{}{Revised by: &\therevised\\}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\theapproved}}{}{Approved by:&\theapproved\\}%
    \bottomrule%
    \end{tabular*}
}


\version{3.2}
\revised{J. Joe}
\approved{A. Uthor}
\begin{document}
\mytable
\end{document}
```

The code runs fine if I comment the `\revised{J. Joe}` line. But if I comment 
`\approved{A. Uthor}`, them the following error is rised:

```
(./example.aux)
! Misplaced \noalign.
\bottomrule ->\noalign 
                       {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
l.34 \mytable
```

Can anyone help me to find the bug?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know precisely what's going on, but it's clearly an expansion problem. It can be solved with more direct syntax:

```
\newcommand*{\version}[1]{\newcommand*{\theversion}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\revised}[1]{\newcommand*{\therevised}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\approved}[1]{\newcommand*{\theapproved}{#1}}

\newcommand{\mytable}{%
  \noindent\begin{tabular}{
    p{\dimexpr 0.4\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
    p{\dimexpr 0.6\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
    }
    \toprule
    \ifdefined\theversion Version: &\theversion\\\fi
    \ifdefined\therevised Revised by: &\therevised\\\fi
    \ifdefined\theapproved Approved by:&\theapproved\\\fi
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
```

There's no need to declare those commands as robust. Moreover `tabular*` is useless and it's necessary to correct the width to take into account the separation between columns.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The actual table is defined inside a sidenote of the `tufte-latex` package, and it is necessary to use the starred version of `tabular` (I don't know why)